# Typing effect in c++

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I’m trying to create a typing effect for the output when the program runs.

Is there an easy way or more practical way to get a typing effect because the only thing I could think of was to make pauses in between the letter but that would be to tedious and annoying to do for an entire program. Also it didn’t even work so there’s that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

 using namespace std;
 

int main() {
  cout << "h";
this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(800));
  cout << "e";
this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(800));
  cout << "l";
this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(800));
  cout << "l";
this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(800));
  cout << "o ";
this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(800));
  cout << "t"; 
this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(800));
  cout << "h";
this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(800));
  cout << "e";
this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(800));
  cout << "r";
this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(800));
  cout << "e\n";
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a loop. `std::string message = "Hello there"; for (char ch: message) { std::cout << ch; std::this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(800)); } std::cout << '\n';` The next trick would be to put that loop into a function so you can call it with any message you want.

Comment: Please 1) learn about [buffered I/O](http://cpptruths.blogspot.com/2005/07/bufferedunbuffered-c-streams.html) and consider using `std::flush`, or unbuffering your output, 2) Consider alternatives for a) organizing your data in some container (the letters you want to print), and b) using a loop to iterate through the elements in the container, Finally: 3) Please INDENT YOUR CODE,

Comment: That's an unnecessary amount of includes (including C headers) for this program, which only requires `iostream`, `chrono` and `thread`.

Comment: Ah ha! And I see why it doesn't work. Computers don't like to waste time on small jobs, so the message you send gets buffered up until there's enough to be worth writing. Add a flush after every write. And even then some terminals don't print anything until they see a newline.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Words_per_minute), _"the definition of each "word" is often standardized to be five characters or keystrokes long in English"_, meaning your program emulates someone who types at the frenzied rate of 15 words per minute! Wow!

Comment: Use `std::flush` after each character. Also consider making the sleep duration somewhat random, as people usually do not have uniform typing speed. You can even go wild an make the pause depend on the letter being typed. You may want to put this in a separate thread so you don't freeze your entire program.

Comment: @bitmask when you say after each character do you mean like inside the quotes are separated by the arrows <<

Comment: @user4581301 I tried the code you put above and I’m not sure if it’s due to the text editor/compiler I’m using but this didn’t work.

Comment: Perfect timing. I just dropped a complete answer below. If that doesn't work for you, let me know, but be very explicit in what doesn't work. It works for me, so if it doesn't work for you I'll have no idea why without details. If I don't know why it doesn't work I won't be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to get into the habit of actually answering questions. A very simple example. Comments inserted inline where it seemed appropriate for explanation

```cpp
// only using the headers needed. The more you include the slower you compile 
// and the more likely you'll run into an identifier used in the library and
// in your code. 
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
// Note the absence of using namespace std; the std namespace exists to 
// mitigate the damage that can be done by naming collisions. If you don't have 
// to be explicit with the names, you'll run into code where the compiler 
// doesn't know if you mean your size function or the std::size function in the  
// standard library. That can get really weird, really fast.

// make a function so you can easily reuse it. Also declutters your code. If
// main does everything, all the bugs are in main, but it's a freaking huge 
// surface area to have to test. You'll have many interlocking tests in a giant 
// web. If the program is broken up into many little functions you can test 
// them all separately with little simple tests without having to worry about 
// how they interact with other code.
std::ostream& typewrite(std::ostream &out,
                     // Why restrict this function to just cout?
                        const std::string &message)
                     // const because no one should change a message while
                     // printing it without a good, well-documented reason
{
    for (char ch : message) // for each character in the message
    {
        out << ch << std::flush; // print one character and flush it to the
                                 // underlying media
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(800));
    }
    out << '\n';
    return out; // return the stream so the caller can test and make sure
                // the writing succeeded
}

int main()
{
    if (!(typewrite(std::cout, "Hello there")))
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to write. How embarassing!\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since I’m new to programming I don’t fully understand this, So is using out instead of cout printing to an outfile ? And I’ve never seen cerr before so I don’t even know what exactly it does

Comment: It's still printing to `cout`, but because we're passing the stream to write to into the function, we can easily change the function to be used with any stream and it costs us absolutely nothing! If you wanted to write slowly into a file (for some insane reason) you now can. If you want to write slowly into a socket stream  to send the message over the internet one character at a time to annoy your friends in chat, now you can! And it's all free because you didn't specify the stream to use in the function inside the function, you just said, "Here, pal, use this stream."

Comment: `cerr` is the counterpart to `cout` for error messages. Bot of them go to the terminal, but you can split them up if you want so that the error messages go to  a log file. Some terminals print them in red so people who aren't colour blind can tell something bad happened. And those of us who are colour blind swear and squint at the screen trying to make out what it says.

Comment: The really cool thing about `cerr` is it's NOT BUFFERED! anything you write is immediately printed. A lot of people screw up when debugging because they print to `cout` and don't realize the message was still sitting in the buffer when the program crashed. They wind up debugging the wrong part of the code looking for the crash because they think the program got as far as it did.

Comment: Alright that’s understandable. And the code works perfectly. The least thing I’m confused about is how the if statement is printing the info. Plus I’m not seeing a call to the function in the main.

Comment: Function called here: `if (!(typewrite(std::cout, "Hello there")))`. It's wrapped up in the `if` statement because you never want to assume something was sent. You want KNOW it was sent. Never trust that something that can easily fail didn't fail. Always make sure. Errors that you don't t look for and handle turn into extra debugging.

Comment: See where `std::cout` is passed into the function? That's where you could use a file or any other type of stream. Just replace `std::cout` with the other stream.

Comment: An if statement runs whatever is inside the condition, then it tests the result. In  this case it runs `typewrite` and then tests the return value from the function to see if it was successful. If it wasn't it prints out the error message.

Comment: Ah I see, I think I get it now , I thought the conditions inside if statements were only used to check previous information above it like if(question == “you good?” I didn’t think that it ran the condition itself

Comment: `question == “you good?"` is the condition, and works needs to be done to make that comparison and return a boolean value. It probably is a function call, `bool operator==(const T& a, const T& b)`, but what the `if` really cares about is the final result, the `bool`.. The trick with the returned `ostream` is `ostream` has a built in conversion function that allows it to be seen as a `bool`, false if any error flags are set in the stream.